# Swap innerHTML for specific time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was trying to change the innerHTML of a div and retrieving it again after a certain amount of time.
For that I have implemented `sleep(miliseconds)` function and used jQuery built-in function as below snippet. The strange thing is that, the code works well in Chrome's debugging mode.

Edited:
I edited the snippet just to show using `setTimeout()`
is not satisfactory in my special case.

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

function swap(time) {
  temp = $(".classname").html();
  $(".classname").html("<p>Swap Content</p>");

  sleep(time);

  $(".classname").html(temp);
}
  
function foo() {
  swap(2000);
  $(".tab1").slideToggle("slow");
  $(".tab2").slideToggle("slow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="tab1">
    <div class="classname">
      <p>Orginal Content in tab1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab2" style="display:none;">
    <div>
      <p>Orginal Content in tab2</p>
    </div>
</div>


<button  type="button" onclick="foo()">Enter</button>
```

Comment: Do not use that sleep.... all it does is lock up the browser. Just use setTimeout

Comment: That `sleep` function doesn’t actually sleep or wait for anything. It just performs a busy loop. No rendering is done in between this execution.

Comment: but I do not want to next instruction would be executed unless this part of the code run

Comment: Well, the bad thing is: *nothing* on that page will react to any user action while your "sleep" loop is running.

Comment: but I put `$(".classname").html("<p>Swap Content</p>");` before sleep, so logically it must be executed before that.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this instead?

```
function swap(time) {
  temp = $(".classname").html();
  $(".classname").html("<p>Swap Content</p>")


 setTimeout(function(){
    $(".classname").html(temp);
 }, time);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single-threaded, so your `sleep` method freezes up the UI and prevents it from refreshing. You should be using `setTimeout` for this purpose instead.

```js
function swap(time) {
  temp = $(".classname").html();
  $(".classname").html("<p>Swap Content</p>")
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".classname").html(temp)
  }, time)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classname">
    <p>Orginal Content</p>
</div>
<button  type="button" onclick="swap(2000)">Enter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code just locks up the browser and prevents rendering. You should be using a timeout. This code will make sure that multiple clicks do not mess up the default text.

```js
function swap(selector, time) {
  var elem = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (!elem.dataset.orgText) elem.dataset.orgText = elem.innerHTML;
  if (elem.dataset.timer) window.clearTimeout(elem.dataset.timer);
  elem.innerHTML = "<p>Swap Content</p>";
  
  elem.dataset.timer = window.setTimeout( function () {
    elem.innerHTML = elem.dataset.orgText;
    // delete elem.dataset.orgText;
    // delete elem.dataset.timer;
  }, time);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="classname">
    <p>Orginal Content</p>
</div>

<button  type="button" onclick="swap('.classname', 2000)">Enter</button>
```

written for jQuery

```js
function swap(selector, time) {
  var elem = $(selector);
  if (!elem.data('orgText')) elem.data('orgText', elem.html());
  if (elem.data('timer')) window.clearTimeout(elem.data('timer'));
  elem.html("<p>Swap Content</p>");
  
  elem.data('timer', window.setTimeout( function () {
    elem.html(elem.data('orgText'));
    // elem.removeData('orgText');
    // elem.removeData('timer');
  }, time));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="classname">
    <p>Orginal Content</p>
</div>

<button  type="button" onclick="swap('.classname', 2000)">Enter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with two JQuery Lines:

```
function swap(time) {
    temp = $(".classname").html();
    $(".classname").html("<p>Swap Content</p>");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".classname").html(temp);
    }, time)
}
```

Please check the Snippet for demo

```js
function swap(time) {
    temp = $(".classname").html();
    $(".classname").html("<p>Swap Content</p>");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".classname").html(temp);
    }, time)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab1">
    <div class="classname">
        <p>Orginal Content in tab1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab2" style="display:none;">
    <div>
        <p>Orginal Content in tab2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="swap(2000)">Enter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function swap(time) {
  temp = $(".classname").html();
  $(".classname").html("<p>Swap Content</p>")
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".classname").html(temp)
  }, time)
}
```

This is the best option!